# How to save a remote server SSL certificate locally as a file

Tags: ssl, certificate

I need to download an SSL certificate of a remote server (not HTTPS, but the SSL handshake should be the same as Google Chrome / IE / wget and curl all give certificate check fail errors) and add the certificate as trusted in my laptops Windows' certificate store since I am not able to get my IT guys to give me the CA cert.

this is for office communications so I cannot really use the actual client to get the cert.

How do I do this, I have Windows 7 and a pile of Linuxes handy so any tool / scripting language is fine.

Comment: To get the certificate of a **mail server**, see http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/70528/how-to-get-ssl-certificate-of-a-mail-server

Comment: Most likely, your browser has a built-in feature for this -- maybe under "developer tools".

Answer (score 424, accepted):

If you have access to OpenSSL, try

```
openssl s_client -connect {HOSTNAME}:{PORT} -showcerts
```

replacing {HOSTNAME} and {PORT} with whatever your values are.

Comment: I prefer this option as I don't have to open a GUI, and I can do it via SSH from our servers.

Comment: Plus it works for protocols other than HTTP.

Comment: [elec3647's solution](http://superuser.com/a/641396/96477) fully automates extracting the PEM in a shell pipeline.

Comment: Is there a way to get this to work behind a proxy?  It doesn't seem to honor the $https_proxy environment variable.

Comment: 443 is the default port for HTTPS.

Comment: I needed `-servername` option  to get the virtual host certificate. https://gist.github.com/Artistan/5219484efb2fe51cd064175b3d0d5971

Comment: For those trying this over IPv6, note that only OpenSSL 1.1.0 and newer support IPv6. See [this LWN article](https://lwn.net/Articles/486369/) for the backstory regarding this.

Comment: Probably obvious, but you have to remove `https://` from the hostname or you'll get `getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`.  The answer is correct, but when you get accustomed to copying/pasting into sites like sslchecker, it's habitual.

Comment: ultra mega kill

Answer (score 363):

A quick method to get the certificate pulled and downloaded would be to run the following command which pipes the output from the -showcerts to the x509 ssl command which just strips everything extraneous off. For example:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect server.edu:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null|openssl x509 -outform PEM >mycertfile.pem
```

To use the certificate, with wget,

```
wget https:/server.edu:443/somepage --ca-certificate=mycertfile.pem
```

Comment: I tried this (on another website) - but was expected the full chain of certs: seems this only brought back the first in the chain - is that to be expected?

Comment: That is not working for me: unable to load certificate
27262:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-50/src/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:648:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE

Comment: I agree with monojohnny, this doesn't give you the full chain.

Comment: Late but @monojohnny: `openssl s_client -showcerts` displays all the certs in the received chain (if connection succeeds), but piping through `openssl x509` takes only the first one and discards the rest. To get all of them instead use `...| sed -n '/^-----BEGIN CERT/,/^-----END CERT/p'` or `...| awk '/^-----BEGIN CERT/,/^-----END CERT/'` You can also use a slightly more complicated `awk` to put each cert in a separate file which makes them easier to use with `openssl` and some other tools.

Comment: To use the certificate, with wget, 
`wget https:/server.edu:443/somepage --ca-certificate=mycertfile.pem`

Comment: using wget it seems to only save a `index.html` => `HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html.1’`

Comment: ..what is x509 ?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 , any hint as to what that "more complicated `awk`" might be?

Comment: @cowlinator: there are variations but something like `openssl s_client ..... -showcerts \
   | awk '/-----BEGIN/{f="cert."(n++)} f{print>f} /-----END/{f=""}'` see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366898/generate-hpkp-fingerprints-for-all-certificate-chain

Comment: While gbroiles' answer does allow you to see the certificate, this answer actually includes the part about saving it to a file.

Comment: `--no-check-certificate` option could be added if certificate already expired.

Answer (score 137):

To be honest, I have never tried this before (never needed to) however, I have just tried in Firefox and it seems to work for saving:

1. Click on the SSL certificate icon at the top / Padlock at the bottom.
2. Click `View Certificate`
3. Click on the `Details` Tab
4. Chose which certificate you want from the hierarchy [not circled in picture]
5. Click `Export`

[image]

Comment: Good to know - but for my curiosity, can you explain a little more what you are trying to accomplish? I have never needed to export a SSL client certificate and am very curious why you would actually have the need to do it...

Comment: That's a server certificate, not a client certificate. The main reason to export a client private key & certificate is to maintain a backup, or if you want to authenticate using another browser or computer.

Comment: @gbroiles - read the question, he used the wrong terminology, but this solved his problem.

Comment: right, and I answered your question - why would someone want to save a client certificate? "SSL client certificate" was your term, not his.

Comment: There is no such thing as a “client part of a server certificate”. In the hierarchy presented you can chose if you want to see/export the main Certification Authority certificate, the sub-CA certificate, or the server certificate. (The chain may be longer, shorter or even incomplete in each case.) – I tried to download the CA certificate from my imap server this way. Failed, because Firefox and co. don’t allow connection on port 143. And to answer “Why?”: I wanted to import it in stupid Thunderbird, which can’t do it itself! (can only make an exception with the server cert, not the CA above).

Comment: Doesn't look like there's a way to do this in Chrome, right?!

Comment: You can do it in Firefox atm.

Comment: @fatuhoku sure there is, see https://superuser.com/a/1160401/112204

Comment: This is no longer possible in modern Firefox.  Those goofballs wanted to "modernize" the cert viewer and took away the ability to export it in the process :(

Comment: @Coderer This is no longer true. I've just checked Firefox 117 and there is a way to download either a single certificate or the whole chain. You need to go to certificate details and find the Miscellaneous section

Answer (score 64):

**Exporting a certificate using the Chrome browser**

1. Connect to the website using SSL (https://whatever)

<del>2. Click on the lock symbol and then click on Details</del>

2. Since Chrome version 56, you do the following: 
   go to the Three Dots Menu -> More Tools -> Developer Tools, then click on the Security Tab. This will give you a **Security Overview** with a **View certificate** button.
3. Click on the **View certificate** button.

   A modal window will open. It has two panes. The top one shows the trust hierarchy of the site's certificate (the last one listed), the intermediate certificate(s), and the root certificate (the topmost one).

   The second, larger pane, shows the details of one of the certificates.

   There may be zero or more intermediate certificates.

   Note that the root certificate has a gold-bordered icon. The others have a blue border.

   See the screen shot below.
4. To export a certificate:

   1. First click on the certificate's icon in the trust hierarchy.
   2. The certificate will be shown in the main part of the modal.
   3. Click on the certificate's large icon in the main part of the modal. **Drag** the icon to your desktop. Chrome will then copy the certificate to your desktop.

[image]

Comment: I had to drag the icon onto a text editor, desktop didn't work for me.

Comment: For Chrome on Windows, after you click 'View certificate' the modal is different than Mac. Click the Details tab and then Copy to File...Then choose the format and filename, which is straightforward.

Comment: When I use Chrome v63 on Mac OS, the text file I get from dragging the certificate is human-readable, but not in any structured format that I can figure out how to convert into machine-readable form like X.509 .crt .

Comment: no difference if opening from address bar or from this dev tab, and still can't download crt...

Comment: Not working anymore on Chrome 72.0.3626.121

Comment: On Mac it is still working with Chrome 72.0.3626.121 for me.

Comment: on mac Google Chrome 
Version 74.0.3729.131 (Official Build) (64-bit) tested work

Comment: But you can also get the **view certificate** modal window by clicking on the padlock icon to the left of the URL; that seems faster to me, than the steps 1 and 2 here? Then just proceed with step 4. chrome Version 83.0.4103.116 (Official Build) (64-bit) on macOS

Comment: If you don't find the security tab (point 2) look at here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64657022/security-tab-missing-from-chrome-developers-tools

Answer (score 29):

**automated**

-servername was required for me to get the right cert from the virtual host on our server.

`openssl s_client -showcerts -connect host.name.com:443 -servername host.name.com  </dev/null | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > host.name.com.pem`

you may also convert to a certificate for desktop

`openssl x509 -inform PEM -in host.name.com.pem -outform DER -out host.name.com.cer`

last part is to add it to your certs, not sure on windows
for mac keychain I used, should be similar...

`sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain host.name.com.cer`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Artistan/5219484efb2fe51cd064175b3d0d5971

Comment: Note that some applications have trouble with the System and SystemRoot keychains (Golang, I'm looking at YOU), so after installing and setting the trust for those levels, you may also want to copy it to your own user's `login.keychain` via the `Keychain Access` app, you can just browse to the certificate in System/SystemRoot and click and drag it to your `login` keychain.

Comment: @dragon788 - my intent was to automate this with command line and this works for me.  Please share here if you find a solution for login.keychain via CLI as well!  thanks!

Comment: judging from what I've read on the web I believe just omitting the `-d` from the command will apply only to the user keychain instead of the System keychain.

Comment: If you are also adding an intermediate certificate(s) you will want to use `trustAsRoot` instead of `trustRoot` in order for it to get correctly added.

Answer (score 20):

This is [gbroiles' answer](https://superuser.com/a/176721/40712), but I wanted to point out that the cURL project [has a page with a few more details](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html) on using `openssl` to save the remote server's SSL certificate:

- ```
  openssl s_client -connect {HOSTNAME}:{PORT} | tee logfile
  ```
- Type `QUIT` and press the Enter / Return key.
- The certificate will be listed between "BEGIN CERTIFICATE" and "END CERTIFICATE" markers.
- If you want to see the data in the certificate, you can use:

  ```
  openssl x509 -inform PEM -in certfile -text -out certdata
  ```

  where `certfile` is the certificate extracted from `logfile`. Look in `certdata`.

Comment: This worked for me. To be a bit more explicit, I edited logfile and trimmed everything that was outside of the BEGIN CERTIFICATE and END CERTIFICATE and saved the result as certfile.pem  (Not sure if the extension was necessary).

Answer (score 4):

This will give the results containing the certificates only

```
echo QUIT | \
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect hostname:port | \
awk '/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/ {p=1}; p; /-----END CERTIFICATE-----/ {p=0}'
```

Comment: I think the double quotation mark on the end can be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

Found a much easier way if on Windows.  Tried Microsoft Edge (pre-chromium) and clicked on the lock in the address bar -> View certificate
Dialog pops up with an "Export to File" button, which saves it as a .crt file.

Not much I'd use Edge for, but this was piece of cake.

Answer (score 0):

on a windowz machine one can retrieve a server certificate on the Windows Terminal prompt and type the following command:

```
openssl s_client -connect www.github.com:443 -showcerts
```

Is a requirement to have installed openSSL. One can download it here:
https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

open the `openSSL/bin` folder and type the command above.