# Save certificate to use with lftp

Tags: certificate, ftps

How can I save a certificate for use with lftp?

The certificate in question is not accepted by lftp when downloaded from the server. I tried

> `openssl s_client -connect {HOSTNAME}:21 -showcerts`

from [How to save a remote server SSL certificate locally as a file](https://superuser.com/questions/97201/how-to-save-a-remote-server-ssl-certificate-locally-as-a-file) but this returns

> CONNECTED(00000003)
>   3074045628:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:766:
>
> no peer certificate available

I am connecting with

> `lftp -p 21 -u {USER} {HOSTNAME}`

and receive

> `ls: Fatal error: Certificate verification: Not trusted`

Answer (score 11):

I think the problem here is that the FTP server uses plain FTP but supports explicit SSL/TLS. So to follow the protocol, the client must connect to the FTP server and invoke encryption through the AUTH command. (AUTH command is sent in plain text)

So to answer your question, I don't think it is possible to show the certificate. Unless you can somehow send the AUTH command to the FTP server.

Edit: To display certs do the following:

> openssl s_client -connect x.x.x.x:21 -starttls ftp

Comment: Brilliant! I've been fiddling with this for a long time until you pointed out the `-starttls ftp` bit!

Answer (score 9):

It seems like lftp is not configured correctly on many systems, which makes it unable to verify server certificates. Maybe this is the underlying cause for your problem.

The web is full of suggestions to fix this by disabling certificate verification or encryption altogether. This is **unsecure** as it allows man-in-the-middle attacks to pass unnoticed.

The better solution is to configure certificate verification correctly, which is easy, fortunately. To do so, add the following line to `/etc/lftp.conf` (or alternatively `~/.lftp/rc`):

```
set ssl:ca-file "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
```

`ca-certificates.crt` is a file that contains all CA certificates of the system. The location used above is the one from Ubuntu and may vary on different systems. To generate or update the file, run [`update-ca-certificates`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/update-ca-certificates.8.html):

```
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

If your system does not have this command, you can create one manually like this:

```
cat /etc/ssl/certs/*.pem | sudo tee /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt > /dev/null
```

Comment: This does not fix the issue for me, even though the server's certificate includes the hostname I'm using. After `set ssl:verify-certificate no`, the connection works fine.

Answer (score 5):

## Warning: other answers here destroy connection security

All those answers that invite to disable certificate verification definitely weaken security as they make the connection vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks.

## Answer that preserve security here

This question [trust server certificate with lftp](https://superuser.com/questions/1414353/trust-server-certificate-with-lftp) mentions this comment [FTP SSL/TLS certificate handling #214](https://github.com/lavv17/lftp/issues/214#issuecomment-197237482) on lftp github site which looks much better.

### Short version

```
set ssl:verify-certificate/FI:NG:ER:PR:IN:T:HE:RE no
```

### Full, tested, working, version

#### For interactive sessions

Password will be asked interactively:

`lftp -e "set ssl:verify-certificate/4E:6F:74:20:72:65:61:6C:20:66:69:6E:67:65:72:70:72:69:6E:74 no ; open user@machine.domaine.name"`

#### For unattended sessions

- put password in a `~/.netrc` file
- notice that syntax is `open myspecificuser@machine.domaine.name` inside commands, and not `lftp myspecificuser@machine.domaine.name`
- `-c` instead of `-e` will execute full command then exit lftp, alternatively add `; quit`.

`lftp -c "set ssl:verify-certificate/4E:6F:74:20:72:65:61:6C:20:66:69:6E:67:65:72:70:72:69:6E:74 no ; open myspecificuser@machine.domaine.name ; cd /some/path/on/server ; mirror "`

Content of `~/.netrc`:

`machine machine.domaine.name login myspecificuser password my-specific-password-not-this-one-of-course`

Comment: It is working for me perfectly. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that this endpoint is correctly secured using SSL?  From the error message you show it seems like the server doesn't provide ssl?  Also the port 21 is mostly used for plainftp not FTPs or SFTP.

This is what I get when I run the command against a plain FTP server

```
openssl s_client -connect xxx.yyy.zzz.www:21 -showcerts
CONNECTED(00000003)
140165093090976:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:749:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 225 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
```

The lftp error can be due to a misconfiguration of lftp where you require ssl.  You can try the following:

```
set ftp:ssl-force false
```

Anyway you can also try a connection using

```
set ssl:verify-certificate no
```

Although this is only acceptable for testing and with test accounts (in order not to leak credentials)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was caused by the server only supporting depreciating versions of TLS that are not supported by modern distributions.

Test if you can connect with openssl:

```
$ openssl s_client  -starttls ftp -connect <hostname>:21

CONNECTED(00000003)
140140192228416:error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol:../ssl/statem/statem_lib.c:1940:
---
<remaining text snipped>
```

This error is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53065682/1878199, tl;dr; debian now requires at least TLS 1.2.

You can check what your server supports by using nmap:

```
$ nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 21 <hostname>

PORT   STATE SERVICE
21/tcp open  ftp
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   SSLv3: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: client
|     warnings: 
|       CBC-mode cipher in SSLv3 (CVE-2014-3566)
|   TLSv1.0: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: client
|_  least strength: A
```

(See also https://security.stackexchange.com/a/70737)

So my server only accepts TLSv1.0. The correct solution would be to update the server, of course!

Possible solutions on client side:

1. Use SSL `$ lftp -e "set ftp:ssl-auth SSL" <hostname>`
2. Disable SSL for this connection `lftp -e "set ftp:ssl-allow no" <hostname>`
3. You can also try to enable obsoleted protocols on your client by editing `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` as described in the first link above. Not recommended.