# trust server certificate with lftp

Tags: ftp, ssl, tls, ftps, lftp

When connecting to a server with lftp, I have the following issue:

```
Certificate verification: Not trusted: no issuer was found (AA:AA:AA:[...]:AA:AA)
```

Which indicates at least that the cert verification failed. I would like to whitelist that certificate.
Obviously, disabling certificate verification is not an option due to security concerns.

Here is what I already tried:

- Following [that guide](https://www.versatilewebsolutions.com/blog/2014/04/lftp-ftps-and-certificate-verification.html) to retrieve certs from the server, and use them with `set ssl:ca-file`. Following that guide, I have three certs. I tried them all, then concatenated together, which didn't change a thing. Also tried with `ssl:cert-file`.
- using the same method as above with `openssl s_client -connect my.server.tld:21 -starttls ftp`, which yields only one certificate
- setting `ssl:ca-file` to the [system's ca store](https://superuser.com/a/1211331)
- using [gnutls-cli](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=532099#c14) works fine with the -s option, so do the above `openssl s_client` commands.

The certificate seems to be signed by a valid chain of trust, as far as those commands report.

Filezilla works fine, but displays the following warning, which might be related:

> Server sent unsorted certificate chain in violation of the TLS specifications

I have no control over the server as I do not host it myself, but the greeter identifies itself as Pure-FTPd.

Other clients that didn't work (lack of support for ftps, or for the specific server): `ftp`, `ncftp`, `dolphin (KIO)`, `curlftpfs`, `tnftp`, `firefox`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution a year later is still to turn off ssl:verify-certificate for specific certificate fingerprints.

```
set ssl:verify-certificate/{fingerprint1} no
set ssl:verify-certificate/{fingerprint2} no
```

See lftp closed issue 214 -- https://github.com/lavv17/lftp/issues/214#issuecomment-197237482

Comment: Thank you, this effectively whitelists the certificate, if I am not mistaken?

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me step by step with lftp:

1. **get certificate** of host with `openssl s_client -connect <ftp_hostname>:21 -starttls ftp`, at the begining of result I got something like `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
   MIIEQzCCAyu.....XjMO
   -----END CERTIFICATE-----`
2. **copy** that `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
   MIIEQzCCAyu.....XjMO
   -----END CERTIFICATE-----` **into** `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`
3. Into **lftp configuration** reference this certificate file adding to `/etc/lftp.conf` for systemwide `set ssl:ca-file "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"`
4. and then do your sync or whatever with `lftp`, on my case it is `lftp -u "${FTP_USER},${FTP_PWD}" ${FTP_HOST} -e "set net:timeout 10;mirror ${EXCLUDES} -R ${LOCAL_SOURCE_PATH} ${REMOTE_DEST_PATH} ; quit"`

Comment: I followed this step by step but still saw the error. Maybe it's indeed an expected behavior of lftp for  self-signed certificates (ref answer from notabot2).

Comment: That openSSL command doesn't work for me on Ubuntu 23.10, I get this error: `402766AF727F0000:error:10080002:BIO routines:BIO_lookup_ex:system lib:../crypto/bio/bio_addr.c:738:Servname not supported for ai_socktype
connect:errno=0
`

Answer (score 0):

The solution was for me to get **all** certificates from the command below and add them to the cert-file.

```
openssl s_client -connect hg-gym.de:21 -starttls ftp -showcerts
```