# pip and SSL certificate errors

Tags: python, ssl, certificate

I am trying to install a library via pip.
I have a problem with SSL certificate, even when using the --cert.
Trying this on windows (pip version 1.5.4,python version 2.7.6):

```
pip --cert C:\tmp\cacert.pem install robotframework-archivelibrary --proxy http://myproxy
```

> Getting page
>   https://pypi.python.org/simple/robotframework-archivelibrary/   Could
>   not fetch URL
>   https://pypi.python.org/simple/robotframework-archivelibrary/:
>   connection error: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:507: error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14):

I had similar error messages due to our corporate firewall intercepting SSL (i.e. a transparent SSL proxy). I exported the root CA cert that signs the firewall certificate in .pem format and appended it to the following file:

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\cacert.pem
```

That resolved my issue. Your issue might not be exactly the same, but if you get the right CA certificates into the above cacert.pem I'm sure you can get passed your SSL certificate verification failure.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how do one export root CA cert?

Comment: Yes, I'm unclear on which root CA is exported to where -- are we grabbing the source repo's root CA and passing it on the command line, as well as exporting to the firewall via the cacert.pem file in Python's site-packages?

Comment: I tried 5 different cacert.pem files in python folders but eventually one of them worked: `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\certifi\cacert.pem`  One of them also got conda to work

Answer (score 4):

Since `--cert` doesn't work for you, probably you're using the wrong certificate file.

Most likely you're behind some corporation proxy, so you should export your root certificate by going to the failing URL (e.g. `https://pypi.python.org/simple/robotframework-archivelibrary/`, see: [How to save a remote server SSL certificate locally as a file](https://superuser.com/q/97201/87805)).

If it's in [CER format, convert it into PEM](https://serverfault.com/q/254627/130437).

Then use that PEM file, e.g.

```
pip --cert root-cert.pem install robotframework-archivelibrary
```

See also: [pip install fails with “connection error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25981703/55075).

Answer (score 2):

If `pip` complains about Certificate errors, then add some hosts `to pip.ini`.
Unfortunately Python 3.x on Win10 does not have any `pip.ini` file,
so you have to create it manually from `powershell/cmd` with:

- `mkdir C:\ProgramData\pip`
- Create a file `C:\ProgramData\pip\pip.ini` with notepad:

  ```
    [global]
    trusted-host = pypi.org (new-line)
                   files.pythonhosted.org
  ```

Check it with `pip config -v list`. You should see this in the last line:

```
global.trusted-host='pypi.org\nfiles.pythonhosted.org'
```

The `\n` denotates a new-line that should be part of the `trusted-host` entry.

Comment: Thanks zx485. i hope it is more clear now.

Comment: This answer worked.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your pip config, which on Windows is `C:\Users\<user>\pip\pip.ini`.

```
[global]
  trusted-host = pypi.python.org
  proxy = <proxy>:<port>
```

Find your proxy by following [these](https://superuser.com/a/346376/578357) directions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it was because my antivirus (Eset "Smart Security") was filtering SSL/TLS.  Disabled that and everything was perfect.